# Gradle sync fails - play-services-measurement-base

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I have a problem on my Android project, I can't build, this is the error I have:

> Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
>   The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.2,15.0.2], [15.0.4,15.0.4]], but resolves to 15.0.4. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

I tried many different solution I found but the problem persists. 
I have the right dependencies and repositories on gradle file on project root:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
```

and

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

On my app gradle I have the following dependencies:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.2"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:15.0.2"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0"
```

Some suggestions?

The solution was update the following dependencies:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.0.0"
```

Comment: update to the latest version

Comment: @KopiBryant what do you mean? Everything is already updated

Comment: Be sure that the offline work in the gradle setting is unchecked.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same exact error, upgrading `analytics` was the key:

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0'`

I know you thought everything is updated referring to the official website, but writing `15.0.0` and looking for suggestions works better.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot!! In my case I need to update also com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager to 16.0.0

Comment: Watch out as I had to downgrade from 16.0.1 to 16.0.0 to make it work.

Comment: Check the newest versions for each lib here: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html

Answer (score 45):

I just added right after the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the bottom of my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// Work around
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this a safe fix, though?

Comment: @JeremyF this solution has been successfully used  since June 2018 in my real projects that have thousands of users but "...THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY..." :)

Comment: Amazing !! Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Update project gradle play service dependency with latest release :
 **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'**
 and

[Update project firebase products usage as per firebase latest release note](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

Comment: Please try to invalidate,clean and rebuild project.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't solve the issue, I updated the question with the solution

Answer (score 6):

this shoud be on top if you use firebase libraries:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0"
```

Comment: For those using this with the android gradle plugin >= 3.1 and google-services=4.1.0 this may be your issue~

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.this shoud be on top if you use firebase libraries:

implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0"

Answer (score 3):

In my case the issue was OneSignal, which somehow broke everything down.

They even have a dedicated library for this: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
and the actual issue was that OneSignal was inside my app-level gradle, instead of root one.

Freaking ridiculous!

Comment: From their Android SDK Install docs it looks like they want it in the `app/build.gradle` https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup

Comment: @JimFactor Yeah, but somehow this was the issue and I've spent like half a day trying to figure it up; ended up this this solution and everything seems just fine since then

Answer (score 3):

Check Answer by Bhupendra Acharya from
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/XbGR-YrsTTA works for you. I got the following error 
The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
While using

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

And resolved by updating the version

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
```

Comment: I am facing similar issues. I am wondering where and in which file one need to add these lines.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I was importing `oneSignal` gradle plugin but I do not import the full `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`.

To fix I just had to add the implementations I was using.

Answer (score 2):

For future users: Open build.gradle files and just hover your mouse on the dependencies and a tooltip gonna show up telling your the newest version and that should solve your problem.

> Beware that Firebase Documentations does not have the newest versions.

Answer (score 2):

update classpath for **com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16+**

```
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: ..in project's `build.gradle` !

Answer (score 1):

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    jcenter()

}
```

Try this one , place maven url on top inside repositories in build.gradle

Comment: @Giorgio I faced same issue,   after placing maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } on top (Before jcenter() ) that worked for me....i am talking about sequences

Comment: I tried it and it didn't solve the issue, I updated the question with the solution

Answer (score 1):

Update build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2' //< update version 
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1' //< update version 
    }
}
```

This would help you I guess

Comment: check my question, they are already updated to the last version

Answer (score 1):

Update the build.gradle file from the project root folder. I've tried this and it was helping.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    google()
}
dependencies {

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    ----
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you added following line in bottom of app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Make sure you are using compatible google-services in project level gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
```

Check if you have added following dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have answered a similar issue here. You need to keep versions of play services and firebase to latest one. Check here for links
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52696667/3333878

Answer (score 0):

**Try to set**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

**instead of**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

**It's helped in my case, but I don't know the cause of the error.**